# Flex project in a CodeIgniter project?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, codeigniter, routes

I have a CodeIgniter project and I made a back-office in Flex.
I was wondering how I can implement the Flex project in my CodeIgniter since I'm working with routing I can't route to any directory.
So there isn't a way to display the back-office.

Does any have any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to edit your htaccess file, exclude the directory backoffice from being routed through code igniter.